# Перегрузка инкремента и декремента для bool

Tags: c#

Существует такая форма увеличения и уменьшения `int`

```
int a = 0;
a++;
++a;
a--;
--a;
```

Вопрос в следующем: Можно ли в пользовательском коде создать аналогичные операции для `bool`? Или придется писать некую обертку для `Boolean` и использовать только её?

Что то вроде:

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool x;
        x = false;
        Console.WriteLine(++x);
        x = false;
        Console.WriteLine(x++);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}   
/*
Output
true
false
true
*/
```

Comment: опишите, как вы себе это представляете

Comment: @Etki Добавил в вопрос

Comment: честно говоря, не вижу в этом большой выгоды

Comment: @Etki Меня интересует именно возможность реализации, применение я найду.

Comment: В C# нельзя перегрузить операторы для существующих типов. Можно использовать методы расширения; можно создать тип-обертку над существующим типом.

Comment: Кстати, в случае `bool`, можно использовать выражение `a ^= true`, которое циклически присваивает переменной `a` значения true/false/true/false/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете переопределить инкремент в существующем типе, но вы можете легко написать враппер. Пример:

```
struct Bool : IEquatable<Bool>
{
    bool value;
    public Bool(bool b) { value = b; }

    public static Bool operator ++ (Bool b) => Bool.True;
    public static Bool operator -- (Bool b) => Bool.False;

    public static bool operator true (Bool b) => b.value;
    public static bool operator false (Bool b) => !b.value;

    public static Bool operator | (Bool b1, Bool b2) => new Bool(b1.value || b2.value);
    public static Bool operator & (Bool b1, Bool b2) => new Bool(b1.value && b2.value);

    public static implicit operator Bool(bool v) => new Bool(v);

    public static readonly Bool True = new Bool(true);
    public static readonly Bool False = new Bool(false);

    public bool Equals(Bool other) => value == other.value;

    public static Bool operator == (Bool l, Bool r) => l.value == r.value;
    public static Bool operator != (Bool l, Bool r) => l.value != r.value;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => (obj is Bool) && Equals((Bool)obj);
    public override int GetHashCode() => value.GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => value.ToString();
}
```

Пример использования:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bool x;
        x = false;
        Console.WriteLine(++x);
        x = Bool.False;
        Console.WriteLine(x++);
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        Bool b1 = Bool.False;
        if (++b1)
            Console.WriteLine("preincreement true");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("preincreement false");

        Bool b2 = Bool.False;
        if (b2++)
            Console.WriteLine("postincreement true");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("postincreement false");

        if (ComputeFalse() && ComputeTrue()) { /* do nothing */ }

        var b3 = (b1 == b2);
        if (b3++) { /* do nothing */ }
    }

    static Bool ComputeTrue() { Console.WriteLine("computing true"); return Bool.True; }
    static Bool ComputeFalse() { Console.WriteLine("computing false"); return false; }
}
```

Вывод программы:

> True
>   False
>   True
>   preincreement true
>   postincreement false
>   computing false

Answer (score 2):

Из спецификации к языку C#(7.6.9):

> Unary operator overload resolution (§7.3.3) is applied to select a
>   specific operator implementation. Predefined ++ and -- operators exist
>   for the following types: **sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long,
>   ulong, char, float, double, decimal**, and any enum type.

Как Вы можете видеть, bool в списке отсутствует и это понятно: базовой семантики для инкремента и декремента булевого флага не существует. Поэтому, Вам придётся делать свой класс и уже в нём перегружать операторы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще для bool есть оператор !, инвертирующий значение переменной:

```
bool x = true;
bool y = !x; // false
```

Comment: Я это знаю. Мне нужна логика аналогичная с `int`, ведь есть разница написания `++a` и `a++`

Comment: Разница между `++a` и `a++` обусловлена тем, что значений целых - много, и по обе стороны от `а` они есть и разные. Булевских значений - всего два, и если Вы хотите получить значение отличающееся от текущего, такое значение только одно.

Comment: @Igor Обновил вопрос. И пускай это может и бессмысленно и не нужно. Я спросил именно есть ли возможность как то перегрузить операторы например или что то подобное, что бы такого добиться.

Comment: @BwehaaFox - Вас понял. К вопросу претензий нет.